# Why is Image inside Ellipse not working in VS2013?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013

I am having a hard time figuring out why this isn't working.
I have put the image property to "Content" also and still nothing.

Here is my code:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Width="744.09448819" Height="1052.3622047">
    <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Name="svg2" Width="744.09448819" Height="1052.3622047">
        <Rectangle xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Width="726" Height="577" Name="rect3336" Fill="#FFECECEC"/>
        <Ellipse Canvas.Left="10" Width="263" Canvas.Top="10" Height="137" Name="path3340" Visibility="Visible">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/1.PNG"/>
            </Ellipse.Fill>

        </Ellipse>
        <TextBlock Name="my_TB" Width="{Binding ElementName=path3340, Path=Width}"
            Height="49" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"
         Text="Avatar" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="53" FontSize="36"/>
        <Ellipse xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="218" Width="266" Canvas.Top="152" Height="143" Name="ellipse2" Fill="#FFFF00FF"  MouseDown="ellipse2_MouseDown"/>
        <Ellipse xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="404" Width="266" Canvas.Top="300" Height="143" Name="ellipse3" Fill="#FFFF00FF" MouseDown="ellipse3_MouseDown"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

If I change it to this, it works:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Width="744.09448819" Height="1052.3622047">
    <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Name="svg2" Width="744.09448819" Height="1052.3622047">
        <Rectangle xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Width="726" Height="577" Name="rect3336" Fill="#FFECECEC"/>
        <Ellipse Canvas.Left="10" Width="263" Canvas.Top="10" Height="137" Name="path3340" Fill="#FFFF00FF" MouseDown="ellipse_MouseDown">
        </Ellipse>
        <TextBlock Name="my_TB" Width="{Binding ElementName=path3340, Path=Width}"
            Height="49" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"
         Text="Avatar" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="53" FontSize="36"/>
        <Ellipse xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="218" Width="266" Canvas.Top="152" Height="143" Name="ellipse2" Fill="#FFFF00FF"  MouseDown="ellipse2_MouseDown"/>
        <Ellipse xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="404" Width="266" Canvas.Top="300" Height="143" Name="ellipse3" Fill="#FFFF00FF" MouseDown="ellipse3_MouseDown"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: There's not a lot to go on there but if I had to guess, could it just be file path issue? Do you get any errors or anything?

Comment: Sorry Chris and thank you.  No errors  I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I can see the image displayed in the design  window so I know it's not a file path issue, but any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Tried using a pack uri instead? Like `pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/blah.png` and set the build action to resource? If it hits in the designer and not at runtime I'd probably try that first.

Comment: For some reason the Local Path was set to System32. Once I used the full path it was ok. I will search how to change the relative path of my project although I have never had to do this before. Thanks!